# Java RSA encryption fails

Tags: java, encryption, rsa

I've written such code which should take 3 arguments, one is file with public key, second file to encrypt and third is file to save encrypted text.
However, it does not work as it should, I added
println just to see where it fails:

```
    public class cipher {
       public static void main (String[] args) throws GeneralSecurityException{
          try {
             FileInputStream keyfis = new FileInputStream(args[0]);
             byte[] encKey = new byte[keyfis.available()];  
             System.out.println(encKey);
             keyfis.read(encKey);
             System.out.println(encKey);
             System.out.println("1");
             X509EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(encKey);
             System.out.println(keySpec);
              KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
             System.out.println("2");
             PublicKey pubKey = kf.generatePublic(keySpec);
              System.out.println("3r");
             Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
             cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,pubKey);   
              System.out.println("4");
               }


         catch(Exception e)
           {}


        }   


}
```

After invokation of program I have such output :

```
[B@938b4a
[B@938b4a
1
java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec@182d86
2
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: Note that reading from a stream like that is not correct. You should use [`readAllBytes`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllBytes(java.nio.file.Path)) if you require a short cut.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first 3 print statements that output something ending with `@938b4a` only show that the object exists, and that the object does not implement `toString()`. Byte arrays should be printed out using hexadecimals.

After that you get to `generatePublic` which fails. This means that your public key - which should be a DER encoded `SubjectPublicKeyInfo` structure - could not be parsed.

Comment: More information could be in the stack trace, of course. Also note that you cannot/shouldn't encrypt data by just using RSA.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what error you're getting, it looks like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9755057/converting-strings-to-encryption-keys-and-vice-versa-java) might be the answer you're looking for.

It appears as though you're trying to encode the private key with the `X509EncodedKeySpec`, when you should be using `PKCS8EncodedKeySpec`.

The public key will then be encoded using the `X509EncodedKeySpec`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the user requires the public key for encryption. Of course the user could mistake the private key for the public key, but the above certainly does not seem to be the answer.

Comment: I am using public key, not private. That is why X509EncodedKeySpec is not the problem in this case.