# Digital Signature in java / android (RSA keys)

Tags: java, android, encryption, rsa, digital-signature

I would like to generate a digital signature in my java/android project with a private key(RSA) stored in DB.

My 2 keys was generated with the below code (*project is in production and I cannot change it*):

```
// Get keys pair (RSA)
KeyPair rsaKyePair = createKeyPair();

// Get private/ public keys and store them in DB
String pri = getPrivateKeyBase64Str(rsaKyePair);
String pub = getPublicKeyBase64Str(rsaKyePair));


public static KeyPair createKeyPair() {
    KeyPair keyPair = null;

    try {
        KeyPairGenerator keygen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        keygen.initialize(KEY_LENGTH);
        keyPair = keygen.generateKeyPair();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    return keyPair;
}

public static String getPrivateKeyBase64Str(KeyPair keyPair){
    if (keyPair == null) return null;
    return getBase64StrFromByte(keyPair.getPrivate().getEncoded());
}

public static String getPublicKeyBase64Str(KeyPair keyPair){
    if (keyPair == null) return null;
    return getBase64StrFromByte(keyPair.getPublic().getEncoded());
}

public static String getBase64StrFromByte(byte[] key){
    if (key == null || key.length == 0) return null;
    return new String(Base64.encode(key));
}
```

Based on different sites ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9755057/converting-strings-to-encryption-keys-and-vice-versa-java) and [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0490__Security/SimpleDigitalSignatureExample.htm)), I'll try to write code for generate a signature:

```
String mySignature = getDigitalSignature("my_string_", "my_private_string" );

/*
 * Generated a signed String
 * @param text : string to sign
 * @param strPrivateKey : private key (String format)
 */
public String getDigitalSignature(String text, String strPrivateKey)  {

    try {

        // Get private key from String
        PrivateKey pk = loadPrivateKey(strPrivateKey);

        // text to bytes
        byte[] data = text.getBytes("UTF8");

        // signature
        Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("MD5WithRSA");
        sig.initSign(pk);
        sig.update(data);
        byte[] signatureBytes = sig.sign();

        return javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(signatureBytes);

    }catch(Exception e){
        return null;
    }

}



private PrivateKey loadPrivateKey(String key64) throws GeneralSecurityException {
    byte[] clear = Base64.decode(key64, Base64.DEFAULT);
    PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(clear);
    KeyFactory fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    PrivateKey priv = fact.generatePrivate(keySpec);
    Arrays.fill(clear, (byte) 0);
    return priv;
}
```

For verify the signature, I use this code in my java API :

```
/*
 * Verify signature of a string
 * @param signature : signature
 * @param origina: original string to verify
 * @param publicKey: user public key 
 */
public static boolean verfiySignature(String signature, String original, String publicKey){

    try{

        // Get private key from String
        PublicKey pk = loadPublicKey(publicKey);

        // text to bytes
        byte[] originalBytes = original.getBytes("UTF8");

        //signature to bytes
        //byte[] signatureBytes = signature.getBytes("UTF8");
        byte[] signatureBytes =javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(signature);

        Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("MD5WithRSA");
        sig.initVerify(pk);
        sig.update(originalBytes);

        return sig.verify(signatureBytes);

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        Logger log = Logger.getLogger(RsaCipher.class);
        log.error("error for signature:" + e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }

}


/*
 * Generate a PublicKey object from a string
 * @ key64 : public key in string format (BASE 64)
 */
private static PublicKey loadPublicKey(String key64) throws GeneralSecurityException {
    byte[] data = javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(key64);
    X509EncodedKeySpec spec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(data);
    KeyFactory fact = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    return fact.generatePublic(spec);
}
```

I've run this code with real data, but the "verifySignature" always returns "False".

I am a newbie in Encryption world, forgive me for my dirty code.

--- EDIT

I got an exception when the verify method is called:

> java.security.SignatureException: Signature encoding error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When signing you returned your signature base64-encoded:

```
return Base64.encodeToString(signatureBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Thus, when verifying you have to base64-decode the signature string. But what you do is:

```
byte[] signatureBytes = signature.getBytes("UTF8");
```

So the `signatureBytes` you try to verify are completely different from the `signatureBytes` you had as a result of signing.

---

You sign using

```
Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("RSA");
```

But You verify using

```
Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("MD5WithRSA");
```

Obviously you should use the same algorithm in both cases.

Comment: In your edits of your question you meanwhile chose `MD5WithRSA` as signature algorithm. MD5 is a bad choice here, much worse than SHA1 and even SHA1 has already been phased out in many signing contexts. If you can change the algorithm, I would propose using a hashing algorithm from the SHA2 family of algorithms, e.g. SHA256. If you have to use MD5, don't expect your signatures to have significant legal value.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. tomorrow I will try with SHA256withRSA. Thank you !

Comment: I've aligned myselfy with the inapp billing of Google Play : SHA1withRSA Thank you again for your help !

Comment: FYI:
calling GetEncoded() on the private key returns null in Android 4.1. 

https://brendanzagaeski.appspot.com/xamarin/0001.html