# Encryption-Decryption not working between the client-sever program

Tags: angular, encryption, rsa, jsencrypt

We are facing issue with the encryption-decryption of data.In server-side we are having decryption java code like this

```
public static String decrypt(byte[] data, PrivateKey base64PrivateKey) throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
    return new String(cipher.doFinal(data));
}
```

For encryption in the client-side we are using jsencrypt.
code looks like this

```
encrypt(numInfo) {
 this.readKeytext('assets/public.pem');
 getKey = getKey.replace(/(^"|"$)/g, ''); 
 if (cardNum.length > 117) { 
 } else {
   this.$encrypt.setPublicKey(getKey);
   this.cypherCardnum = this.$encrypt.encrypt(numInfo); 
   return this.cypherCardnum;
 }
}
```

We are using the RSA-3072 key generation technique for creating public and private keys. Can anyone suggest me the best way of doing the encryption in angularjs that will suit with the server-side implementation?

---

**Update:**

Sample:

Original data : `4000000000000002`

Private key :

```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```

Public key :

```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```

Encrypted data:

```
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
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal base64 character 2e at
java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode0(Base64.java:714) at 
java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode(Base64.java:526) at
com.ibsplc.ps.common.utils.RSAUtil.getPrivateKey(RSAUtil.java:63)
```

---

**Update:**

```
public static PublicKey getPublicKey(String base64PublicKey){ 
    PublicKey publicKey = null; 
    try{ 
        X509EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64PublicKey.getBytes()));
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA"); 
        publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(keySpec); 
        return publicKey; 
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) { 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) { 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    } 
    return publicKey; 
}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. Encryption with JSEncrypt and decryption with Java using a 3072 bit keypair worked for me. You should describe the problem in more detail: How does the error occur, is there an exception? Does the problem affect all keypairs or only certain ones? Can you provide sample data: test keypair, plaintext, ciphertext (e.g. Base64 encoded)?

Comment: You should also justify why you're using this for transport security instead of TLS...

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal base64 character 2e
 at java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode0(Base64.java:714)
 at java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode(Base64.java:526)
 at com.ibsplc.ps.common.utils.RSAUtil.getPrivateKey(RSAUtil.java:63)
This is the we are getting.

Comment: If switching to TLS is an option, it should be done, which would also eliminate the need for troubleshooting. Anyway: The posted keys are valid and belong together. The private key is in PKCS8 format, the public key in X509 format, both as PEM, but without header and footer. On my machine I can use this keypair to encrypt data with JSEncrypt and decrypt it in Java.

Comment: The decryption of the ciphertext posted by you results in an _empty_ string (and not `4000000000000002` as expected). Here you would have to check if the posted test data might be wrong or if the plaintext to be encrypted gets lost somewhere _before_ encryption.

Comment: The exception was thrown in `com.ibsplc.ps.common.utils.RSAUtil.getPrivateKey`, which may indicate that there is a problem when importing the private key. If possible, post the method or debug through the implementation to determine the reason more precisely.

Comment: Is it possible to share a working sample (both frontend and backend logic) to sureshak07@gmail.com ?

Comment: I'm sorry, this isn't the way SO wants it. I'd try to solve the key import issue first. Debug or post the corresponding code, more precisely the `getPrivateKey`-method. Alternatively, you can test other implementations, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9755391) (with `RSA` instead of `DSA`).

Comment: https://travistidwell.com/jsencrypt/ this is the front end code we are refering.

Comment: public static PublicKey getPublicKey(String base64PublicKey){
        PublicKey publicKey = null;
        try{
            X509EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64PublicKey.getBytes()));
            KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
            publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(keySpec);
            return publicKey;
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return publicKey;
  }

Comment: Please post relevant informations in the question and not as a comment (especially methods, as formatting is restricted in comments). Furthermore, the problematic function is rather `getPrivateKey` and not `getPublicKey` (see the exception posted before). Also, please post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that the issue can be reproduced.

Answer (score 0):

I made changes in both the client and server side. Then it worked.
Client side change :  this.cypherCardnum = this.$encrypt.encrypt(cardNum.toString());

In server side : Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/None/PKCS1Padding);